# RedisCustomConversions using Redis Repository

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-repositories

Is it possible to use custom Redis converters with Spring-Data Repository?
I see the example in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.hashmappers.jackson2 but I get the following error when I try it.

```
@Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition: Root bean: class 
[org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.RedisCustomConversions]
```

My code to register the converter is

```
 @Bean
fun redisCustomConversions():RedisCustomConversions {
    return RedisCustomConversions(listOf(MyWriterConverter(), MyReaderConverter()))
}
```

for connection pool I am using LettuceConnectionFactory

any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @No_One. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, at the time didn't get any solution, but I remember someone mentioning it has something to do with the package of the Customer Convertor , but I did not have the code to try it.