# Spring Bean Override for Spring-Data REDIS

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to override RedisCustomConversions [initial post] ([RedisCustomConversions using Redis Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280275/rediscustomconversions-using-redis-repository)and) noticed some inconsistent behaviour.

When I run the spring boot app from IDE I get the error mentioned in the above post, but it works fine if the app is executed using **java -jar myapp.jar**. Which sounds okay but that makes me question if this behaviour is consistent? i.e will my overloaded bean will always be wired? or is it random?

I also noticed from **/actuator/beans** endpoint that when executed in IDE I get this

```
redisCustomConversions: {
  aliases: [ ],
  scope: "singleton",
  type: "org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.RedisCustomConversions",
  dependencies: []
```

But running from the command line I see this.

```
redisCustomConversions: {
  aliases: [ ],
  scope: "singleton",
  type: "org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.RedisCustomConversions",
  resource: "class path resource [com/my/project/cache/config/RedisConfig.class]",
  dependencies: [
   "MyWriterConverter",
   "MyReaderConverter"
]
```

So the question is, can we rely on this behaviour? or it's random and for some deployments, the default RedisCustomConversions will be loaded and for other my custom RedisCustomConversions will be loaded (this will crash the application as data format in REDIS will be different)?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you and after banging my head against wall for longer than I wish to admit I asked in the spring-data gitter. They responded as so:

> When using Spring Boot, you need to declare `@EnableRedisRepositories` and the `@Bean` definition for `RedisCustomConversions` on the same configuration class. That's currently a limitation of how `@EnableRedisRepositories` is built.

Comment: thanks for your reply Taylor, I have moved out of the project so don't have the code to try it out. but this will help if I have to use it in the future.